# Using triggers for referential integrity

Tags: sql-server

There are 2 tables in the database that contain the following columns:

1. `department` table with column `dept_no` (char(4), not null)
2. `employee` table with column `dept_no` (char(4), null)

The `dept_no` column needs to be defined as a primary key in the `department` table and a foreign key in the `employee` table using a trigger.

I thought this was the correct solution using the deleted and inserted virtual tables to update/delete the foreign key in the corresponding employee table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_delete_dept_no
ON department 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
    UPDATE employee 
    SET employee.dept_no = NULL
    FROM deleted 
    WHERE employee.dept_no = deleted.dept_no

CREATE TRIGGER trig_update_dept_no
ON department 
AFTER UPDATE
AS  
      UPDATE e 
      SET e.dept_no = i.dept_no
      FROM employee e 
      INNER JOIN inserted i ON e.dept_no = i.dept_no
```

However, when I update the department `dept_no` row to a different value I do not see the corresponding `dept_no` update in the employee table:

```
UPDATE department 
SET dept_no = 'd4' 
WHERE dept_no = 'd3'
```

Deleting functions as expected. What am I doing wrong with the update trigger and how can I combine these two triggers into one trigger?

Comment: Start by explaining why you do not have actual foreign keys - which would do much of this for you automatically. And in your update example, you are not thinking all the way through your example. In the trigger, your department now has d4 - but there is no employee with department d4, only those with d3. That's a hint - think about your join logic.

Comment: You're right I misunderstood what these virtual tables are used for. I thought they stored the previous values before the update or delete but they actually store the current values as seen by this trigger:

CREATE TRIGGER trg ON department FOR INSERT AS SELECT * FROM inserted

Its part of the homework assignment to use triggers for referential integrity. Normally I'd use the primary key constraint for ensuring integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in your design. The first thing is you should not use dept_no as PK (Primary Key). You need to have an IDENTITY or GUID column as Primary Key and refer to that column as FK (Foreign Key).

This way you won't need to worry about changing the dept_no.

The second point is you don't need trigger. you can use CASCADE option on DELETE action.

[Find more information on CASCADE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why add a surrogate key when a simple natural key already exists? Same as on delete cascade there is on update cascade...

Comment: It is recommended the pk should be a field that user never see in presentation later

Comment: Recommended by who?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you FLICKER and SMor for helping me think through this. I do not believe the assignment wants us to modify the tables by adding IDENTITY or GUID columns and since we are to strictly use Triggers, this is the best solution I can come up with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_delete_dept_no ON department  AFTER DELETE AS 
    UPDATE employee 
    SET employee.dept_no = NULL
    FROM deleted 
    WHERE employee.dept_no = deleted.dept_no

CREATE TRIGGER trig_update_dept_no ON department AFTER UPDATE AS
    IF UPDATE(dept_no)
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT employee.dept_no
            FROM employee, inserted
            WHERE employee.dept_no = inserted.dept_no) IS NULL
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                RAISERROR ('Integrity constraint violation, TRIGGER: 
                            trig_update_dept_no, TABLE: department',16,1)
            END
        ELSE PRINT 'Update successful'
        END
```

This will allow updates to occur in the department as long as there are no orphaned records in the employee table.

Comment: referential integrity should be enforced by foreign key constraints, not by triggers.

Comment: The assignment does not allow foreign key constraints to be used. Otherwise in any other situation I would use foreign key constraints instead of triggers.

Comment: Looks like this was the answer the professor was looking for. Got full credit for the problem. Thanks again for everyone's help!

Comment: Well, unless it's a "let me show you the wrong way first so I can so you the right way" kind of thing, I would say your professor should probably learn a thing or two.

Comment: @ZoharPeled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1785-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16  "You can enforce referential integrity in several ways. Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI) is the most basic way, but it is also the least flexible one. If you need more flexibility, but you still want a high degree of integrity, you can use triggers instead."